# How to remove a module path from the table of contents in Sphinx PDF

Tags: pdf, latex, python-sphinx

I would like to improve view of contents and remove this path because it is too long, or decrease font size or do something else that helps.

[image]

I tried pointsize, but it didn't work.

```
latex_elements = {
    'papersize': 'letterpaper',
    'pointsize': '8pt',
}
```

Comment: A [mcve] may be helpful.